# Is there a way to read/get fps in spritekit swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, frame-rate

Is there a method to get the value of fps in swift?

No I dont mean changing the frameInterval
and no I dont mean

```
skView.showsFPS = true
```

I want to get the fps so that I can have my app wait until fps reaches 60 before it starts the game. For some reason my app occasionally gets 'stuck' at 40fps lingers for 5 seconds then slowly climbs to back to 60. This usually happens when I summon the ControlCenter.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You need to figure out why your app took a while to warm up instead of hack round the problem by check FPS value.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out myself. I have browsed through multiple similar questions on stackoverflow,  but theres no true definite answer as to why it does that. Solutions that apply to other users doesnt apply in my case. I too prefer to know why its doing that instead of searching for a workaround but after spending many days on debugging I still have no clue.

Comment: Good question.  It's utterly normal in game development to need to know your FPS at any given time.

Answer (score 9):

You can calculate it yourself.

Doing something like this in your scene:

```
var lastUpdateTime: TimeInterval = 0

func update(currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    let deltaTime = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    let currentFPS = 1 / deltaTime
    print(currentFPS)

    lastUpdateTime = currentTime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to get the FPS of the view itself independent from which scene is presented, using `SKViewDelegate` (taken from the Developer Documentation, just with the added FPS property):

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController, SKViewDelegate {
    
    let spriteView: SKView = SKView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.spriteView.delegate = self // Set the view's delegate to the ViewController.
    }

    let targetFps: TimeInterval = 60 // Set to your preferred fps
    var lastRenderTime: TimeInterval = 0
    var fps: TimeInterval = 0.0 // Access this property to get the view's fps
    
    // Delegate method:
    public func view(_ view: SKView, shouldRenderAtTime time: TimeInterval) -> Bool {
        
        if time - lastRenderTime >= 1 / targetFps { // Check if the scene should render.
            
            // Determine the fps with the time since the last render:
            self.fps = 1 / (time - lastRenderTime)
            // Set the last render time to the current time:
            self.lastRenderTime = time
            // Let scene know that it should render the next frame.
            return true

        }
        else {
            return false
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

gameView.showsStatistics = true